# Why does a Schmitt trigger work in saturation region?

Tags: operational-amplifier, linear, saturation, schmitt-trigger

Given this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmAxYH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to prove that the opamp works in saturation region as instructed in the first answer to this question : [How are positive and negative feedback of opamps so different? How to analyse a circuit where both are present?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/how-are-positive-and-negative-feedback-of-opamps-so-different-how-to-analyse-a)

So, we have

$$
V^- = V_{in} 
$$
$$
V^+ = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_{out}
$$
$$
V_{out} = A_v(V^+ − V^-)
$$
$$
V_{out} = A_v(\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} V_{out} − V_{in})
$$
$$
\lim_{A_v\to\infty}\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \lim_{A_v\to\infty}\dfrac{Av}{Av \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1}
$$
$$
\lim_{A_v\to\infty}\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = 1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1} 
$$
\$\frac{Vout}{Vin}\$ is finite, even though the feedback is positive! Why is the circuit working in saturation region instead of the linear one?

Am I missing something here?!!

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the following equation: $$\lim_{A_v\to\infty}\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \lim_{A_v\to\infty}\dfrac{Av}{Av \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - 1}$$

Answer (score 2):

When you solve positive feedback circuits like this, you need some initial values.

We can say that \$V_{sat+}\$ as the upper limit to what the opamp can drive to and \$V_{sat-}\$ as the lower limit.

If we make an initial assumption that \$V_{out} = V_{sat+}\$ then you will get 
$$ V_+ = V_{sat+}\dfrac {R_1}{R_1+R_2} $$
$$ V_{out} = A_v(\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} V_{sat+} − V_{in})$$

When \$V_{in} < \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} V_{sat+}\$ the output will be \$V_{sat+}\$
When \$V_{in} > \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} V_{sat+}\$ the output will be \$V_{sat-}\$

You would do the exact same procedure with an initial assumption that \$V_{out} = V_{sat-}\$ to see when you would see a transition going in the opposite direction.

Check out page 7 of [Opamp circuits - Comparitors and Positive Feedback](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/24_op_amps3.pdf)

Comment: Yes you're right, and I am familiar with this way of seeing things.. What I am wondering is, what is wrong with the equations above?

Comment: Bumped to top, I'm interested in knowing what's wrong too as I thought this method worked everytime because the equation was actually describing the internal working of the amplifier (happily surprised to see my initial post was useful to you as well ;) ).

Comment: It must have something to do with Vout/Vin being correct only IF Vout is not restricted to +Vsat/-Vsat (which is impossible) but I'd like to see a proper demonstration because it's only intuitive for now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **positive feedback and the noise** always tends to force the amplifier into saturation. Assume \$V_{in} = 0\$, at power on, your output \$V_{out}\$ is zero. Any input disturbance that might try to force \$V_{out}\$ away from zero will elicit opposite response. The positive feedback is in the same direction as the perturbation, tending to reinforce it. This will drive the amplifier into saturation.

---

**Update:**

Actually, there are some problem in your third equation. You've assumed the amplifier working in the "linear region" already.

If

$$
V_{out} = A_v(V^+ − V^-)
$$

When \$A_{v}\$ goes to \$\infty\$, by positive feedback, the input should to \$\infty\$ too, \$V_{out}\$ should be infinite then, then you'll blow out the universe. If you want the output finite, and have a infinite \$A_{v}\$, your input should tend to zero, this is just negative feedback does.

Comment: The first paragraph in your much appreciated answer means that  the amplifier would start working in one of the saturation regions. As for the third equation, I believe it's always true: if V+ is different from V- then the opamp works in saturation, if not then it's a constant(infinity multiplied by zero)

Comment: Working not mean there must exist the linear relation between input and output.

Comment: I am afraid the third equation is always true for an ideal op amp