# Confusion in identifying positive/negative feedback of opamp for a given circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, feedback

I was reading this post [How are positive and negative feedback of opamps so different? How to analyse a circuit where both are present?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/how-are-positive-and-negative-feedback-of-opamps-so-different-how-to-analyse-a) for identifying positive/negative feedback of op-amp circuit.

Consider the circuit shown in figure(1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCbWdI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to the approach suggested by **nidhin**:
$$v_-=v_{in}=1.6 \quad (\text{by inspection})$$
$$v_+=\frac{4}{3+4}v_o=\frac{4}{7}v_o$$
Now substituting in the formula: \$ v_{o}=A_{ol}(v_+−v_−)\$ , we get:
$$v_{o}=A_{ol}(\frac{4}{7}v_o− 1.6)$$
$$\implies v_o (1- \frac{4}{7}A_{ol} )=-1.6 A_{ol}$$
$$\implies v_o =\frac{-1.6 A_{ol}}{1- \frac{4}{7}A_{ol} }$$
$$\implies \frac{v_o}{1.6} =\frac{- A_{ol}}{1- \frac{4}{7}A_{ol} }$$
$$\text{so, } A_{cl}=\lim_{A_{ol}\to \infty} \frac{v_o}{v_{in}} =\lim_{A_{ol}\to \infty} \frac{v_o}{1.6}=\lim_{A_{ol}\to \infty} \frac{- A_{ol}}{1- \frac{4}{7}A_{ol} }=\frac{-1}{- \frac{4}{7} }=1.75$$
Now, as \$ A_{cl}\$ is finite , \$ \implies \$ net feedback is negative

But according to the approach suggested by **Alfred Centauri**:
Assume there is a net negative feedback, \$\implies \$  the non-inverting and inverting input voltages are equal
$$\therefore 1.6=\frac{4}{7}v_o$$
$$\implies v_o= 2.8$$
However, $$ A_{cl}= \frac{v_o}{v_{in}}=\frac{2.8}{1.6}= 1.75>0 $$
which is a \$ {\color{red}{\text{red flag}}} \$ since inverting-amplifier should have negative gain
Hence, our assumption is wrong
so according to this approach, net feedback is positive
which is making me confused;
Hence,

> 1)Identify the net feedback in figure(1) with explanations
> 2)If the circuit in figure(1) is in net negative feedback, then where did i make a mistake in implementing Alfred's ideas, or
> If the circuit in figure(1) is in net positive feedback, then where did i make a mistake in implementing nidhin's ideas

UPDATE:
If we use a non-ideal voltage source \$ V_{in}=1 \$ volt with \$ R_s =1 K \Omega \$ , i.e,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6AO8H.png)</sup>
then, please explain the type of feedback

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original circuit. But you still mixed up which op-amp terminal is connected to the circuit input.

Comment: I have tried my best to improve this post, now if the post is OK, then please remove the downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both configurations are in use. Both circuits represent a "Negative Impedance Converter" (NIC).

However (for Rf=feedback resistor to the input path, Rx=feedback resistor to the other input and Ro=grounded resistor),

- the **first** circuit (input at the **inverting** amplifier) is called "open-circuit stable" and - for stable operation - we require a source resistance **RS>RfRo/Rx**
- the **second** circuit (input at the **non-inv**. input) is called "short-circuit stable" for **RS<RfRo/Rx**

**Application**: A combination of both versions leads to a very versatile active block which is always stable (Generalized Impedance Converter, GIC). The NIC (non-inv. input) is used as a basic building block for a non-inverting integrator (DEBOO integrator).

Comment: Why we require a source resistance \$ R_S > R_f \cdot \frac{R_o}{R_x} \$ for stable operation for the **first** circuit? could you please derive this relation

Comment: The answer is simple: Because for stable operation, the negative feedback must govern over positive feedback. Hence, Rs/Rf>Ro/Rx.

Answer (score 5):

You have mis-represented the circuit in the previous question which was given as this:

[image]

In the original the input is applied to the non-inverting op-amp input. In your version you connected the input to the inverting input.

If you use an ideal voltage source to provide the input to this circuit, then there is no positive feedback, because the feedback signal is shorted out by the very low resistance of the voltage source.

> which is a red flag since inverting-amplifier should have negative gain

The original problem presented a non-inverting amplifier, not an inverting amplifier.

In your version of the circuit, this is indeed a red flag. It shows you you have made a wrong assumption when you assumed the net feedback is negative. In fact in your circuit the net feedback is positive, because the negative feedback signal is shorted by the ideal voltage source.

Comment: If we use a non-ideal voltage source \$ V_{in}=1\$ volt with \$ R_s=1K \Omega \$ , then will the negative feedback signal still be shorted?

Comment: please explain what mistakes i have made using nidhin's approach

Comment: The error in nidhins approach is as follows (see 3rd line): Using vo=Aol(v+-v-), he automatically has assumed that the opamp works in its linear amplification range.  But this assumption is wrong due to missing negative feedback.