# Op-amp question: Is this circuit possible?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier

I was (re)doing some electronic learning, and tried to come with a "general solution" for all op-amp circuits.

I thought I could do so by having an op-amp with both negative and positive feedback, and both voltage accross + and -.

But, when I combine both equations V+ - Vs  and V- - Vs, I end up with a solution where Vs cancel out. Am I missing something? In this general case, is V+ - V- still equal to zero?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112472/how-are-positive-and-negative-feedback-of-opamps-so-different-how-to-analyse-a  ?

Comment: LittleP, for your specific case I get:$$v_s=\frac{v_p\cdot\left(1+\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}\right)-v_n\cdot\left(1+\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}\right)}{\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}-\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}}$$It's not exactly a [differential amplifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html) in the usual sense of that phrase. *(If you need to see how that equation arrives, I can write it up.)*

Comment: You can start by examining each half in isolation. Here, \$v_-=\frac{v_n\,\cdot\, Z_{rn}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_n}{Z_n\,+\,Z_{rn}}\$ and \$v_+=\frac{v_p\,\cdot\, Z_{rp}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_p}{Z_p\,+\,Z_{rp}}\$. Just equate those two to find \$\frac{v_n\,\cdot\, Z_{rn}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_n}{Z_n\,+\,Z_{rn}}=\frac{v_p\,\cdot\, Z_{rp}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_p}{Z_p\,+\,Z_{rp}}\$ and solve for \$v_s\$. That's all there is to it, I think. It's not complicated.

Comment: We can calculate everything - however, the result is valid only in case the negative feedback portion is larger than the positive one. Otherwise, the circuit is unstable. With other words: The shown equation V(+)-(V-) =0 assumes stability and linear operation with effective negative feedback

Comment: thanks @periblepsis, it is indeed not complicated, I did a mistake writing the i+ and i- equations where V+- are missing...which led me to my mistake. Is it possible to put your comment as an answer? So I can close my question.

Comment: @LittlePanic404 Done. I also added LvW's caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by examining each half in isolation, as voltage dividers:

$$\begin{align*}
v_-&=\frac{v_n\,\cdot\, Z_{rn}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_n}{Z_n\,+\,Z_{rn}}
\\\\
v_+&=\frac{v_p\,\cdot\, Z_{rp}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_p}{Z_p\,+\,Z_{rp}}
\end{align*}$$

Then, since the opamp attempts to keep this equal to each other, simply set them equal:

$$\frac{v_n\,\cdot\, Z_{rn}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_n}{Z_n\,+\,Z_{rn}}=\frac{v_p\,\cdot\, Z_{rp}\,+\,v_s\,\cdot\,Z_p}{Z_p\,+\,Z_{rp}}$$

And then solve for \$v_s\$:

$$v_s=\frac{v_p\cdot\left(1+\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}\right)-v_n\cdot\left(1+\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}\right)}{\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}-\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}}$$

However, this only works when \$\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}\gt\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}\$. Otherwise, with the denominator negative, a positive change in \$v_p\$ would be met by a negative change in \$v_s\$ (wrong direction) or a positive change in \$v_n\$ would be met by a positive change in \$v_s\$ (also the wrong direction.) And, of course, \$\frac{Z_n}{Z_{rn}}=\frac{Z_p}{Z_{rp}}\$ is forbidden as well since that would be division-by-zero.

Here's an example run where \$v_s=3.5\times di\!f\!f\$ where \$-3\:\text{V}\le di\!f\!f\le 3\:\text{V}\$:

[image]